# Unity: Injecting Service from parent into child

Tags: .net, unity-container, ioc-container

If I have the following class structures:

```
public AContainer : IContainer
{
    public AContainer(ILogger log, IDataService dataService)

    ....         
}

public BContainer : IContainer
{
    public BContainer(ILogger log, IDataService dataService)

    ....         
}

public DataService : IDataService
{
    public DataService(ILogger log, ISomethingElse somethingElse, IWhatever whatever)

    ....
}
```

And I want to register two different instances of the same DataService -- one to inject into AContainer and one to inject into BContainer -- while injecting the AContainer's log into its DataService and the BContainer's log into its DataService.

One route seems to be leading me towards registering the full structure, using ResolvedParameter, which feels uncomfortable because I need to register the ISomethingElse and the IWhatever along with the Container.

Another route leads me towards property injection, which is generally discouraged, but may have a place here.

So is there a common pattern for this kind of problem in IoC and is it supported by Unity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe Unity's `PerResolveLifetimeManager` can help you. If ILogger is configured whith `PerResolveLifetimeManager`only a instance is created per injection chain.

With this Life-Time Manager Unity creates a new `Logger` when a `DataService` is resolved (and `DataService` is resolved to be injected in `AContainer` when you resolve `AContainer`), and inject the same created `Logger` in `AContainer`.

A new `DataService` and a new `Logger` will be created when you resolve `BContainer`. This new `logger` will be injected in this new `DataService` and in `BContainer`; `DataService` will be injected into `BContainer`.

The result will be:

2 diferent `Containers`: `AContainer` and `BContainer`.
2 diferent `DataServices`: One in each container.
2 (not 4) `Loggers`: `AContainer` shared the logger with its `DataService` and `BContainer` shared other `logger` with its `DataService`.

Comment: Finally got chance to give this a try and it would have worked, except that our Logger was being resolved for property injection, after the containers were both generated. Unity Child Containers gave me a solution in the end, but thanks for your answer anyway; it helped me down the right path.